# Using SVNs with IIS

Tags: svn, iis

I'm reading this in a hand-over document for a piece of software I'm meant to be working with. It doesn't make any sense to me:

> It's a good idea to tie the website on the server to an SVN (e.g. Google Code) in the IIS so that code doesn't have to be moved from local machines to the server manually. When configured properly, simply committing the code to the SVN will update the website on the server.

What the writers are saying is that if I somehow tie this website to an SVN I won't have to manually move code to the server. Is this just total BS? I can't find any info for it on the internet.

Comment: in short its not BS whats that text says , its a good way of code movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like they are just recommending a way of using SVN to deploy a website. They are saying "Checkout the code on your IIS server" say, from a branch called `Production`. You do all of your work in `trunk`. When it's time to go to production; you just merge your changes into the Production branch; remote into the IIS Server; and do an SVN Update.

It's a simple way of deploying by using SVN as an intermediary. It works around copy-paste, which is prone to (human) errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could set it up this way but its not necessarily an SVN thing. There would be couple ways to go about it. The two that come to mind would be to have have a script that runs `svn up` on the site at a designated interval - not sure how you do that in windows but in *nix land you would use `cron`.

Another way would be if your SVN server is running on the same machine as your webserver... then you could set up a post commit hook to call `svn up` on the live site or to do an `svn export` to staging area and then move the files to the live area when the export is complete.

And then there is always some kind of dedicated Continuous integration suite.

Were it me though i would want an admin to have to log into the server and manually use `svn up`... at least in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If the Live site Code is coming through SVN files , then if you change the code locally and commit , then a simple SVN update will update the live site code as well , i think this is what it means. Eliminating the need for code deployment

Comment: Can this actually be done? How do I make it so that the live site code is "coming through SVN files"?